# Is it acceptable to ask a question with the express purpose of answering it yourself?

Tags: discussion, support, question-appropriateness

I have a few experiences with my phone that I think others might find useful, but I haven't seen questions relating to those particular issues.  Is is considered bad form to ask and answer your own question before any other users interact with the question?

Comment: I of course don't know the reasoning behind SE's rule for this, but I agree with the rule because it will attract users to the site.  Someone Googling might see your question, which wouldn't have been here otherwise, and come here instead of continuing their search.  We want to be a fairly comprehensive resource :)

Comment: @Matthew Read - That was my thinking as well, but I wanted to make sure it was cool before I went forward.  I'm fairly certain there's some kind of system limits for accepting your own answers as well, which I think is perfectly acceptable (and highly necessary, to be honest).

Comment: Yep, I believe you can't accept your own answer within 48 hours.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://android.stackexchange.com/faq

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

It's also good form to give others a chance to answer your question before accepting an answer.