# Would a question about a software annoyance fixed by an update be too localised?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on [an annoyance I had with the gmail app on android on a tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44254/how-do-i-get-the-tablet-gmail-client-to-allow-me-to-swipe-to-archive-like-the-ph) - turned out that shortly after I asked the question, a new version fixed the issue, and as far as I'm concerned its fixed. 
I'm new here, so, I'm wondering how can I make my questions and answers better.

I do wonder though whether at this point my original question is somewhat localised - and might have done better not being asked at all. I'm wondering, what's the Android Enthusiasts community standard on this - is it something that would generally be asked anyway since not all platforms may be on the latest version of the software ? Should I have added in the version of gmail client itself in my original question?

Answer (score 5):

If you know that in advance, your question should obviously not be asked at all (as the issue is already fixed *and recognized as "too localized"*). However: if you only find out about that solution later, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question providing the solution (see: [Is it ok to answer your own question and accept it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/192154)).

Of course at some point such a question will become "too localized", as (in your example) noone would be using that faulty GMail version anymore a year after. So after providing your answer and accepting it, it might be a good idea to either vote-to-close as "too localized" or flag it such for moderator attention, depending on what your reputation permits you to. This way it might be easier recognized when someone runs a "cleanup batch" later, so it could be deleted (mod) or vote-to-delete'd (10k+ user) when it is outdated.

See also:

- [Is it acceptable to ask a question with the express purpose of answering it yourself?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/452/16575) (Meta ASE)
- [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) (Meta SO)

Comment: I didn't know at the time, and both these devices are are 'new' and identical. I also cross checked with someone with a different tablet who has the same 'issue'. This is all very embarrassing, since I'm reasonably familiar with the SE system, and this wouldn't have happened with an OS I was more familiar with. Will self select and flag the question as such.

Comment: No problem, as stated above. I would even go so far and say "even if you know in advance", in case you *know* the problem is *wide-spread and affects many users,* and thus might prove valuable (even if for a short time) -- as SE ranks quite high with Google search results. Still, the recommendation with flag/vtc stands :)

Comment: I see no benefit in closing questions if they have a valid answer, that is why I don't see a need to close them as "too localized", even if the issue does not exist any more. Furthermore, while GMail app updates are most likely received by all devices, there are cases where an app update is never delivered to an device (because of vendor/carrier or minimal required Android version restrictions, etc). The information that an app once had a bug that was fixed with an particular update is usually valuable, so I think the best idea is answer your own question and mark it accepted.

Comment: i would distinguish between issues that are unlikely to and/or shouldn't happen (declining a Gmail update and complaining about bugs) versus things that can't happen (playing an unpatched version of an MMO for example).  Questions about fixed bugs in MMOs should be closed as TL whereas I think it's OK for fixed bugs in apps that you have the option of updating to remain open.  Super User wouldn't close a question about Office 2007 for example.

Comment: Indeed, there are no "hard lines", and each case needs to be checked on its own -- as Matthew's comment indicates. Also, there's a difference between "close" and "delete": IMHO Flow's "GMail" question should be closed (but *not deleted*); it's still there for reference then, and can be re-opened when it seems fitting. But that's *my* opinion; if my co-Enthusiasts state otherwise, I of course obey :)